# How to write this product function in a compact way?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, products

Consider the following function (all roman symbols are integers)

$$
f(x) = (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)
$$
Then 
$$
f'(x) = (x+2)(x+3) + (x+1)(x+3) + (x+1)(x+2)
$$
Now I want to find a way to write this in a sum/prod way and I thought of this:
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{m \geq 1 }^{3} \, \prod_{i=m}^{(m+1)\text{mod}3} (x+i) 
$$
then for $m=1$ we get the product $(x+1)(x+2)$, for $m=2$ we get $(x+2)(x+3)$ and for $m=3$ we get the product $(x+3)(x + 4\text{mod}3) = (x+3)(x + 1)$ which gives buck what we originally wanted.

My question is a) is the notation ok? and b) wether it is safe to generalise this to the following: if 
$$
f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x+i)
$$
then
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{m \geq 1}^{r}\prod_{i=m}^{(m+r-1)\text{mod}r}(x+i)
$$
is the correct result?

Comment: One can write it as $f'(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{3}\frac{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}{x+m}$.

Comment: $f'(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \frac {f(x)}{x+i}$ as @mathlove put it.

Comment: This expression is symmetric and cyclic. In inequalities we often write $ab+bc+ca$ as $\sum_{cyc} ab$. I don't know if this notation helps here.

Comment: the other suggestions are more elegant in this particular example, but for general "skip an index" notation a common way to write such a product is: $f'(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{r}\prod_{i = 1, i \ne m}^r(x-i)$

Comment: Is my suggestion wrong?